# How do I install an updated scipy on the dotCloud platform?

Tags: scipy, dotcloud

Adding "scipy" to my `requirements.txt` file results in a number of errors. What else do I need to do? I see things like:

```
Running setup.py egg_info for package scipy
10:19:24 [www]     /home/dotcloud/env/build/scipy/scipy/__init__.py:97: UserWarning: Numpy 1.5.0 or above is recommended for this version of scipy (detected version 1.3.0)
10:19:24 [www]       UserWarning)
10:19:24 [www]     Running from scipy source directory.
10:19:24 [www]     blas_opt_info:
10:19:24 [www]     blas_mkl_info:
10:19:24 [www]       libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /home/dotcloud/env/lib
10:19:24 [www]       libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/local/lib
10:19:24 [www]       libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/lib64
10:19:24 [www]       libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/lib
10:19:24 [www]       NOT AVAILABLE
```

etc.

(this question and answer are being migrated from answers.dotcloud.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the version of numpy installed on the dotCloud Python service is too old, so you need to add the following to your `requirements.txt` file before scipy to upgrade to a newer version.

```
numpy==1.6.1
```

scipy also requires some system packages that aren't installed by default `libatlas-base-dev` and `gfortran` in order to build it correctly. You can add these in a `systempackages` section of your `dotcloud.yml` file, like this:

```
systempackages:
    - libatlas-base-dev
    - gfortran
```

Once you scipy to your `requirements.txt` and the systempackages to `` `dotcloud.yml ``, repush. This should fix your issue, and scipy will be installed.

It is also important to note that it will take a little while to build all of those items so the first push might take a few minutes, so don't be surprised if it is taking longer then usual.

(original answer from Ken Cochrane)